# hyperref + glossaries + latex = bad spacing around math relations

Tags: math-mode, spacing, hyperref, glossaries, dvi

Compile the following input with latex && dvips (which you sometimes have to do for a variety of reasons; my case is recompiling old documents):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{productOrder}{name={product order}, text={\sqsubseteq}, sort=productOrder, description={foo}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\(A \sqsubseteq B\) (good spacing)\\
\(A \gls{productOrder} B\) (bad spacing)\\
\(A \not\sqsubseteq B\) (good overlaying)\\
\(A \not\gls{productOrder} B\) (bad overlaying)
\end{document}
```

What you get is wrong spacing around the glossary entry and that the slash does not match the symbol:

[image: compilation result].

You can also see wrong spacing and overlaying when viewing the dvi file (the links are not hidden there, btw.).

Of course, you can always go with `\mathrel{\gls{productOrder}}` and `\not\mathrel{\gls{productOrder}}`. Doing it on each use is, well, tedious, though we could (probably) write a macro for that.

However, compiling the above file with pdflatex produces right spacing and the right overlay, which makes me think that there is a bug inside the hyperref-glossaries package chain. Any bugfix? Exchanging the order of loading the two packages resolves the problem, but the documentation of Nicola advises against it.

Comment: You get the same problem with `\hyperlink{glo:productOrder}{\sqsubseteq}` which is what `\gls{productOrder}` is doing, so this seems to be a feature of `\hyperlink` with `latex`+`dvips` rather than a problem with `glossaries`. (Sorry about the bug tracker not working. The stupid web hosting company decided to remove a load of Perl modules without notice, and without the ability to reinstall them, so all my Perl cgi scripts have stopped working. I'm currently looking for a new web hosting company.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot a suggestion below but it could be a key on `\newglossaryentry` rather than a hack into `\hyperlink` (if you are passing by that code again one day:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The next version (1.21) of `glossaries-extra` will have the ability to switch from the default `\hyperlink{target}{\glstextformat{link text}}` to `\glstextformat{\hyperlink{target}{link text}}`. I'll add an answer once I've uploaded it (but there are a few other things that also need sorting out first).

Comment: @LeonMeier It's quite possible that Heiko's already noticed this question since it has the `hyperref` tag, but you could submit a bug report. The simplest MWE that demonstrates the problem is `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{hyperref} \begin{document} \hypertarget{target}{Target} $A \sqsubseteq B$ $A \hyperlink{target}{\sqsubseteq} B$ \end{document}` It may turn out to be a feature of the dvi engine as `hyperref` in general works much better with pdflatex.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following (with a bit more effort could be integrated as (say) a `mathclass=mathrel` key in the existing keyval list but
here as a command that you can optionally define to force a math class around a defined gls entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries




\let\oldhyperlink\hyperlink
\def\hyperlink#1#2{\glsmaththing{\oldhyperlink{#2}{#2}}}
\def\glsmaththing{\csname mathclass\detokenize\expandafter{\glslabel}\endcsname}

\newglossaryentry{productOrder}{name={product order}, text={\sqsubseteq}, sort=productOrder, description={foo}}
\newcommand\mathclassproductOrder{\mathrel}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\(A \sqsubseteq B\) (good spacing) \\
\(A \gls{productOrder} B\) (bad spacing)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default commands like `\gls` (when used with `hyperref`) essentially do:

```
\hyperlink{target}{\glstextformat{text}}
```

As noted, this works fine for the PDF engine but not with the DVI engine.

The extension package, [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra), now (as from version 1.21, 2017-11-03) provides a boolean key `hyperoutside`. The default `hyperoutside=true` behaves as per the norm for the base `glossaries` package:

```
\hyperlink{target}{\glstextformat{text}}
```

The setting `hyperoutside=false`, switches the commands around:

```
\glstextformat{\hyperlink{target}{text}}
```

Since it's a bit of a nuisance to have to do `\gls[hyperoutside=false]{productOrder}` all the time, the category attribute `hyperoutside` can be set instead.

The extension package provides an additional key `category` that can be used when defining entries. The value is just a label, so you could define your `productOrder` entry as:

```
\newglossaryentry{productOrder}{
  category=mathrelation,
  name={product order},
  text={\sqsubseteq}, sort=productOrder, description={foo}}
```

The `mathrelation` category can then have the `hyperoutside` attribute set to `false`:

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{mathrelation}{hyperoutside}{false}
```

This means that `\gls{productOrder}` will now behave like `\gls[hyperoutside=false]{productOrder}`, but it won't affect any other entries that you define (unless they also have `category=mathrelation`).

Now that `\glstextformat` is outside of `\hyperlink` it could be redefined to `\mathrel`:

```
\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\mathrel{#1}}
```

but that will cause a problem for all your other entries.

This new version of `glossaries-extra` also recognises another attribute `textformat` which may be set to a control sequence name (without the leading backslash) identifying a command (that takes a single argument) that may be used instead of `\glstextformat`:

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{mathrelation}{textformat}{mathrel}
```

This means that instead of doing

```
\glstextformat{\hyperlink{target}{text}}
```

any entry defined with `category=mathrelation` will do:

```
\mathrel{\hyperlink{target}{text}}
```

All other entries will behave as normal.

Here's a complete example including `hyperoutside=true` for comparison and `colorlinks` to highlight the hyperlinks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\glssetcategoryattribute{mathrelation}{hyperoutside}{false}
\glssetcategoryattribute{mathrelation}{textformat}{mathrel}

\newglossaryentry{productOrder}{
  category=mathrelation,
  name={product order},
  text={\sqsubseteq}, sort=productOrder, description={foo}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\(A \sqsubseteq B\)\\
\(A \gls{productOrder} B\)\\
\(A \gls[hyperoutside]{productOrder} B\)
\end{document}
```

[image: A ⊑ B A ⊑ B A⊑B]

For the negation, I recommend defining a command that moves the `\not` inside the link text:

```
\newcommand*{\notgls}[2][]{\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{\not\glsentrytext{#2}}}
```

Updated MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\glssetcategoryattribute{mathrelation}{hyperoutside}{false}
\glssetcategoryattribute{mathrelation}{textformat}{mathrel}

\newglossaryentry{productOrder}{
  category=mathrelation,
  name={product order},
  text={\sqsubseteq}, sort=productOrder, description={foo}}

\newcommand*{\notgls}[2][]{\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{\not\glsentrytext{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\(A \sqsubseteq B\)\\
\(A \gls{productOrder} B\)\\
\(A \not\gls{productOrder} B\)\\
\(A \notgls{productOrder} B\)
\end{document}
```

[image: A ⊑ B A ⊑ B A /⊑ B A ⋢ B]

Comment: @LeonMeier I've updated my answer.

Comment: @LeonMeier I don't get a correct overlay with pdflatex and `\not\gls{productOrder}` and `glossaries-extra` (only with the base `glossaries`). I think there's too much stuff at the start of `\gls` (especially with `glossaries-extra`) for `\not` to function properly. (There's a lot of initialisation at the start of commands like `\gls`, processing  options, setting defaults etc.) David's answer only works with `glossaries` not with `glossaries-extra`.

Comment: @LeonMeier No, it just means there's no `\printglossary` (or `\printglossaries`) in the example. I omitted it for simplicity since it wasn't relevant. If you add the glossary (`\makeglossaries` in the preamble and `\printglossary` in the document) the warning should go away once the associated file has been created by `makeindex`.